# PHP appears to define null as itself. How does this work?

Tags: php, null

A colleague of mine discovered, by ctrl-clicking on `null` in PHPStorm, that PHP defines `null` as

```
define ('null', null, true);
```

in `core_d.php`.

1. Why does PHP need to define null at all?
2. How does this even work? How can it define `null` as itself?

My best theory so far is that perhaps `null` is defined already, but using `define` allows adding a case-insensitive alias, so to speak. I don't know enough about PHP to judge the likelihood of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`core_d.php` belongs to PHPStorm not PHP itself. [See the file on github.](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/Core/Core_d.php) PHP is written almost entirely in C. The file probably exists to help with code insights and static analysis. From the [README file of the stubs repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/README.md):

> STUBS are normal, syntactically correct PHP files that contain function & class signatures, constant definitions, etc. for all built-in PHP stuff and most standard extensions. Stubs need to include complete PHPDOC, especially proper @return annotations.
>
> An IDE needs them for completion, code inspection, type inference, doc popups, etc. Quality of most of these services depend on the quality of the stubs (basically their PHPDOC @annotations).

However, as pointed out by [Bartosz Zasada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349893/bartosz-zasada) php does define a constant called null. It is currently defined in [line 137 of `ext/zend/zend_constants.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_constants.c#L137) in the php source code at the end of `zend_register_standard_constants()`.

Comment: Still, it's worth noting that there actually is a constant in PHP named `null`, and its value is, you know it, `null`: https://3v4l.org/3T6Na. This was done probably to avoid people redefining value keywords in PHP.